# "between()" function with only right or left inclusive

Tags: python, pandas

all I am trying to filter some dates with pandas. 
I initially tried doing that with this code

```
bd = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018], # billing data
                    'month': [9, 10],
                    'day': [14, 15]})
bd = pd.to_datetime(bd)
month1 = (df2.Date >= bd[0]) & (df.Date < bd[1])
```

I would get the error of TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'

However, when I did the between() function

```
bd = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018],
                    'month': [9, 10],
                    'day': [14, 15]})
bd = pd.to_datetime(bd)
month1 = df2[df2['Date'].between(bd[0], bd[1])]
```

It worked, but it would include the 15th of October which I do not want. The between() function is useful, but I would like to now what alternatives I have if I only need one side inclusive, and the other exclusive. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think between also supports a parameter called inclusive.

```
month1 = df2[df2['Date'].between(bd[0], bd[1], inclusive='left')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix for `between` is simple. You subtract one day on the side which you want the 'exclusive'. In your case, it is like this

```
a_day = pd.DateOffset(1)
month1 = df2[df2['Date'].between(bd[0], bd[1] - a_day)
```

---

Otherwise, if you really want totally control on the inclusiveness of sides, you need to use `pd.IntervalArray` or `pd.IntervalIndex`

Comment: My days are separated by 15 minute intervals, so I think I will just separate by minutes if possible. The data will be day 23:45 and (day + 1) 0:00

Comment: @LuisEnriquez-Contreras: `DateOffset` supports minute-offsets. Just specify option `minutes` within it as   `pd.DateOffset(minutes=15)` for 15 minutes offset